# Javascript - Regex coordinates

Tags: javascript, regex

Say you have to parse strings to match something like this :

```
913|723
```

being `xxx|yyy` the coordinates.

How do I check with javascript and regex if the string matches the `xxx|yyy` (only numbers and the separator) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (/^\d+\|\d+$/.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
^   # Start of string
\d+ # One or more digits
\|  # literal |
\d+ # One or more digits
$   # End of string
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex pattern

```
^\d{3}\|\d{3}$

var pattern = '/^\d{3}\|\d{3}$/';
if (pattern.test(subject)) {
    alert("matched");
}
```

You can online test [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Comment: This is not correct. It will report a match on `"abc123|234def"`.

Comment: You can try it above regex online test suite, and you will see that "abc1|2def" wont match